# Database restoration problem on SQL Server Big Data Cluster

Tags: sql-server

I deployed a SQL Server Big Data Cluster (in Active Directory mode) on an on premise Kubernetes cluster (Kubernetes version = 1.18.2).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/deploy-active-directory?view=sql-server-ver15

The Kubernetes Cluster is made up of 3 (vSphere) VMs, 1 Master and 2 worker.

Also a 4th (NFS server) VM is configure as a Dynamic Storage Provider.

I managed to copy and restore databases from `.bak` files, but only when the database size is less than 15 GB.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/data-ingestion-restore-database?view=sql-server-ver15#copy-the-backup-file

My initial hunch was that the default value for (data) Persistent Volumes was 15 GB; so I customized that value to 100 GB and re-deployed the SQL Server BDC.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/concept-data-persistence?view=sql-server-ver15#configure-big-data-cluster-storage-settings

But still restoration of Databases larger than 15 GB fails with the following error...

> PMStarted executing query at Line 1
>   Msg 42019, Level 16, State 4, Line 2
>   RESTORE MANAGED DATABASE operation failed. Internal service error.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

A side (2nd) question, is it possible to the change the edition/License of the deployed pods in BDC..???

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the volumes are created with the correct size (using kubectl)?

Regarding licensing, all pods will have the same edition/license as your master instance - unless I misunderstand your question?